# mysql query does not find the latest record but the first one

Tags: mysql

I have the following table `patient`:

| id | status | first_name | last_name | father_name | department | face_dev_id | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | x | x | x | x | x | ......... | ....... |

I also have the following `patient_case_number` table:

| id | id_number | case_number | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020 | 2021-04-18 12:17:10 | .... |
| 2 | 1 | 3030 | 2021-04-18 12:22:20 | .... |

Now I have the following query:

```
SELECT p.id_number, p.first_name, p.last_name, p.father_name, p.department, f.case_number
FROM poria.patient AS p
JOIN (
    SELECT pcn.id_number, pcn.case_number
    FROM poria.patient_case_number AS pcn
    ORDER BY pcn.created_at ASC
) AS f
ON f.id_number = p.id
WHERE p.face_dev_id = 'x'
LIMIT 1
```

Long story short -
My target is, given `face_dev_id` value, get the latest `case_number` value off `patient_case_number` table.

This is how it should work:
Given `face_dev_id` value - search in `patient` table matching record with same value of `face_dev_id` (Note that this column is UNIQUE). Then - find the latest `case_number` value off `patient_case_number` table (using the `created_at` value). Search it in this table using the `id_number` column which matches the `id` column in `patient` table.

Currently this query would return me `case_number=2020` but not `case_number=3030` (and I need it to be 3030). Can you help fixing it?

Comment: you should sort the result of the join, not the table you are joining to. and ASC is ascendiding, LIMIT 1 will find the row with the lowest value

Comment: Why `ASC` in `ORDER BY pcn.created_at ASC`?  ASC stands for Ascending.....

Comment: Are you sure that the answer you accepted returns what you want? By placing LIMIT 1 inside the subquery you return the most recent row of the table `poria.patient_case_number` which may or may not match anything of the filtered table `poria.patient`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `LIMIT 1` in the inner query and change it from `ASC` to `DESC` - otherwise it would query the first one by most late `created_at`:

```
SELECT p.id_number, p.first_name, p.last_name, p.father_name, p.department, f.case_number
FROM poria.patient AS p
JOIN (
    SELECT pcn.id_number, pcn.case_number
    FROM poria.patient_case_number AS pcn
    ORDER BY pcn.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
) AS f
ON f.id_number = p.id
WHERE p.face_dev_id = 'x'
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ORDER BY` clause inside the subquery is useless.
You should place it in the outer query:

```
SELECT p.id_number, p.first_name, p.last_name, p.father_name, p.department, f.case_number
FROM poria.patient AS p JOIN poria.patient_case_number AS f
ON f.id_number = p.id
WHERE p.face_dev_id = 'x'
ORDER BY f.created_at DESC -- you get the latest with DESC not ASC
LIMIT 1
```